# How we can split the text in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I have the list of items with comma in between and I want each of them in single separate line.

Using split we can get this but I don't know how to make it out.

Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Using split we can get this but I don't know how to make it out."? It sounds like you are successfully turning your list into an array, but it's not clear what you are trying to do after that.  Can you also share a sample of your code (or something equivalent that we can run) so that we can see what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

The split filter takes on a substring as a parameter.
The substring is used as a delimiter to divide a string into an array.

**Here is the example that might help you.**

```
<!-- input -->

{% assign beatles = "Apple, Mango, Orange, Banana" | split: ", " %}

{% for member in beatles %}
  {{ member }}
{% endfor %}

<!-- Output -->
Apple
Mango
Orange
Banana
```

**For further more please check below link**

https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/string-filters#split